# Genetrating the coordinate map for AI detection using three js

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, three.js

I want to generate the map coordinates which is demo in the the following example. I understand the code but can't get how the developer has generated the map coordinates.
http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2012/06/how-build-first-person-shooter-browser-threejs-and-webglhtml5-canvas.
http://icecreamyou.github.com/Nemesis/game.html running example.

Moreover same map thing is used in HTML5 game TEACHMETOFLY

Please help me regarding this map generation??

Answer (score 0):

That map is a game level so it was probably generated with photoshop or similar tool.

Comment: Can you elaborate more how could i do this i am very newbie to photoshop